# Can I select certain third-party drivers to disable in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, safe-mode

I am in a complicated situation where my PC is constantly rebooting on its own. I've verified it isn't my RAM, SSD, USB devices, etc. It is possible that its' my PSU, as there's no clear way to test it. However, Windows 10 works perfectly fine without these random reboots in Safe Mode with Networking.

This leads me to believe a driver is the culprit, but now I am struggling to determine which driver is causing the issue. Is there some way within Windows that I can individually detect and disable non-Windows/third-party drivers, so that I can use process of elimination to figure out the problematic driver?

Comment: Start with MSCONFIG and load only necessary drivers.  Then add drivers and see if you can determine what driver is causing restart.

Comment: Also, let Windows try to find the issue with SFC and DISM.